# Error handle in Meteor in calling server side method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I call a method for deleting family from server/publicationMehods like this:

```
    deletedFamily(family) {
      if (Meteor.user().roles[0] == "admin") {



         var myUsers = Meteor.users.find({"profile.family_id": family._id}).fetch();

         for (var i = 0; i < myUsers.length; i++) {
           UsersDeleted.insert(myUsers[i]);
           Meteor.users.remove(myUsers[i]);
          }

         var myGuests= Guests.find({"profile.family_id": family._id}).fetch();

         for (var i = 0; i < myGuests.length; i++) {
           GuestsDeleted.insert(myGuests[i]);
           Guests.remove(myGuests[i]);
          }

         FamiliesDeleted.insert(family);
         Families.remove(family);

      }
}
```

I want to handle exception and catch it if any errors happend and in frond-end show the result. I know there is not any transaction in Meteor. But I need to show the result to user at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Meteor, if you want to return an error to a user from a Meteor method then you throw an exception, but it must be a [`Meteor.Error`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-Error) exception object in order to send it back to the client.

On the client side, when you call a Meteor method on the server, you provide a callback function that receives an error and result.  If you wish to display an error to the user then whatever `Meteor.Error` exception object that was thrown in the method will be in the `error` callback argument.

Here is an example.  First let's look at the meteor method throwing an exception.

```
Meteor.methods({
  deletedFamily: function(family) {
    //... your logic here...

    if (somethingWentWrong) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("logged-out", "The user must be logged in to delete a family.");
    } else {
      return // something
    }
  },
});
```

On the client, you would call the method like this and if an error was thrown it will be in the `error` object.

```
// on the client
Meteor.call("deletedFamily", function (error, result) {
  // identify the error
  if (error && error.error === "logged-out") {
    // show a nice error message
    Session.set("errorMessage", "Please log in to delete a family.");
  }

  //...continue on with your logic...
});
```

If you need to pass along an exception generated by something else (mongodb for example), then just use [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) blocks and pass a `Meteor.Error` when needed.  Here is an example.

```
Meteor.methods({
  deletedFamily: function(family) {
    //... your logic here...

    try {
      // Mongodb insert or update
    } catch(e) {
      if (e instanceof WriteError && e.code === '11000') {
        throw new Meteor.Error("duplicate-error", "The family already exists.");
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: What is somethingWentWrong? is it a know property in Meteor?

Comment: No, that is just a silly example to represent whatever you would check in your logic to determine that an exception needs to be thrown.  The point is, your logic would know when an error occured and if it does you would throw the exception.

Comment: thanks. yes, that's logical error messages that I can pass to client. But I dont know how to catch server-side errors.like duplicate keys ...

Comment: I just get Internal server error [500] error when server break with this error : `Exception while invoking method 'insertDeletedFamily' WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: meteor.families_deleted index: _id_ dup key: { : \"DGG6H2v6CkGJNAHDg\" }","op":{"_id":"DGG6H2v6CkGJNAHDg","city":"*","address":"*","primary_contact":"*","primary_contact_phone":"*","smoking":"*",` .I want to handle this kind of errors

Comment: It sounds like that error is coming from mongodb because you are violating a duplicate index. You can handle this by wrapping a [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) around your collection insert or update where this is happening, catch the mongodb error, then throw your own `Meteor.Error` for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use throw/catch.

Read the following document:

[Throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)